# How to evaluate a pyTorch/DGL tensor

Tags: pytorch, dgl

From a DGL graph I want to see the adjacency matrix with

```
adjM = g.adjacency_matrix()
adjM
```

and I get the following which is fine:

```
tensor(indices=tensor([[0, 0, 0, 1],
                       [1, 2, 3, 3]]),
       values=tensor([1., 1., 1., 1.]),
       size=(4, 4), nnz=4, layout=torch.sparse_coo)
```

Now I want to have the adjacency matrix and the node values each by itself. I imagine something of this kind:

```
adjMatrix = adjM.indices   # or
adjMatrix = adjM[0]
nodeValues = adjM.values   # or
nodeValues = adjM[1]
```

But this form is not estimated by pyTorch/DGL.
My beginner's question:

- how to do this correctly and sucsessfully? and
- is there a tutorial for a nuby? ( I  have  searched a lot just for this detail...!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Click [here](https://docs.dgl.ai/en/0.9.x/generated/dgl.DGLGraph.adj.html?highlight=adj#dgl.DGLGraph.adj)!
You will find the usage of `dgl.adj()`.  As the doc said, the return is an adjacency matrix, and the return type is the SparseTensor.

I noticed that the output that you post is a SparseTensor.

You can try it as follows then you can get the entire adj_matrix

I create a dgl graph `g`, get the adjacency matrix as `adj`

```
g = dgl.graph(([0, 1, 2], [1, 2, 3]))
adj = g.adj()
adj
```

output is:

```
tensor(indices=tensor([[0, 1, 2],
                       [1, 2, 3]]),
       values=tensor([1., 1., 1.]),
       size=(4, 4), nnz=3, layout=torch.sparse_coo)
```

We can find that `adj` is the presence of sparse, and the sparse type is coo, we can use the following code to verify if `adj` is a SparseTensor

```
adj.is_sparse
```

output :

```
True
```

so we can use `to_dense()` get the original adj matrix

```
adj.to_dense()
```

the result is:

```
tensor([[0., 1., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 1., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0., 1.],
        [0., 0., 0., 0.]])
```

When you have a problem with DGL you can check the Deep Graph Library Tutorials and Documentation.